# How to set up dev and API server from create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've started a new app with `create-react-app`, and ejected from that. I made a small express server as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('build'));
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at: http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

In `package.json` I've added a line, `"proxy": http://localhost:3000",` as well as switching the commands:

```
"scripts": {
    "run": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "start": "node server.js",
  },
```

`run` used to be `start`.

However now of course when I run `npm start` and go to localhost:3000, I get `Cannot GET /`. I need this server to receive and return local API calls I'll be making from my app, but I also want it to run a hot-reloading dev server just like the old `npm start` (now `npm run`) command did. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I made a [fork](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/2605) of the create-react-app repository adding webpack watch option because of this same reason. It might help you.

Just to add more info, I really invested time looking on how to get webpackdevserver to build the "bundle.js", and found that it is not possible because it loads the bundle into memory but doesn't persist it, so the file is never created. The only way available is the webpack watch option but, I don't understand why the create-react-app team can't add it to the repo, it's a really requested feature, and there are more forks than mine that solves this issue. So, you have three options:

1. Use the proxy server in package.json (if it works)
2. Make your own fork and add the watch option, or use an existing one
3. Don't use create-react-app